# Google Site Verification file

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console

A client has a WordPress site, where they in 2013 uploaded the Google Site Verification file to the media gallery in stead of the root of the web host.

This causes Search Console to say that the file is not mobile friendly.

If I were to move the file from the media gallery to the root, would this fix it?

And what would I have to do to update it in Search Console, Analytics and so on?

Or is there another way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

After you add your site to Google Search Console, you should see an option to download an HTML verification file in the Recommended method tab. Download this file to your computer.